# TypeError missing 'base_field' at django inspectdb on ArrayField

Tags: django, postgresql, model, inspectdb

django 2.2.1

Legacy database was created via sql code and I want to get model via `inspectdb`.
The problem column was created as `times VARCHAR[]`

When I run `inspectdb > models.py` - execution failed with an error. The `models.py` file was created as empty file and I see error in console:

`times = ArrayField(blank=True, null=True) #This field type is a guess
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument 'base_field'`

For this legacy database -

1) Should I overwrite every table manually since inspection is failed?

2) Could I use database cursor without any models (in production too) ?

3) Are there other solutions?